# Why is the partial derivative function an isomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis

"Let $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ be a mapping of class $C^1$ with m < n. Assume $f^{'}(x_0)$ is surjective for some $x_0$. Then let E = Ker $f^{'}(x_0)$. Then by assumption on the dimensions, E $\neq \emptyset$. Select F such that $E\bigoplus F = R^n$. Then since $f^{'}(x_0)$ surjective, $D_2f(x_0): F \rightarrow R^m$ is an isomorphism. "

My question is why E is not empty and $f^{'}(x_0)$ surjective implies $D_2f(x_0): F \rightarrow R^m$ is an isomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ cannot be empty, it might at most be trivial (i.e., contain only the zero vector). Howver, we have 
$$ \dim \ker f'(x_0)=\dim \Bbb R^n-\dim \operatorname{im}f'(x_0)\ge n-m>0.$$

After that, $\dim F=\dim\operatorname{im}f'(x_0)=m$ by surjectivity and $f'(x_0)|_F$ is injective, hence $f'(x_0)|_F\to\Bbb R^m$ is an isomorphism

Comment: OP might need for the isomorphism theorems used here to be mentioned explicitly, but we'll see if he accepts the answer.